# Handling single click and double click events on activeX button in VBA

Tags: vba, mouseclick-event

I would like to handle single click and double click events separately for an ActiveX button in VBA.  My issue is that the single click event is called for both single and double clicks.  Is there a way to supress/bypass the single click procedure when a double click event occurs? I'm sure there's a simple answer for this, but can't find anything on the web...

Answer (score 0):

From Help

> If there is code in the Click event, the DblClick event will never trigger, because the Click event is the first event to trigger between the two. As a result, the mouse click is intercepted by the Click event, so the DblClick event doesn't occur.

Try capturing Mouse Down and Mouse Up, wait 500 ms, if no Mouse Down, then it's a single click, if there is wait the time for a mouse down.

DoubleClickSpeed 
HKCU\Control Panel\Mouse

Data type Range Default value 
REG_SZ  100 - 900 (milliseconds in decimal)  500

Answer (score 0):

[Brad Yundt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2855094/byundt) provides this clever workaround at Experts-Exchange in [this post](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/Q_28278891.html).

*I have assumed you have asked this wrt Excel- pls let me know if I am mistaken*

> You might try using Application.OnTime to schedule a response to a
>   leftclick after say a 1 second delay. If a doubleclick or rightclick
>   occurs in the meantime, then the leftclick event in the OnTime sub
>   will not occur.
>
> The following code goes in the code pane for the worksheet being watched. Note that it uses the code name for that worksheet, not the tab name.
>
> As written, the code watches A1:A10 for either a leftclick, rightclick or doubleclick on a single cell. It then displays a message box naming the cell that was clicked and the type of click.

**worksheet event code**

```
Dim bTrapped As Boolean
Dim cel As Range, rgWatch As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(cel, Target) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Doubleclick at " & cel.Address
    bTrapped = True
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(cel, Target) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Rightclick at " & cel.Address
    bTrapped = True
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim targ As Range
Set rgWatch = Range("A1:A10")
Set targ = Intersect(Target, rgWatch)
If Not targ Is Nothing Then
    If targ.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        bTrapped = False
        Set cel = targ.Cells(1, 1)
            'Allow 1 second for user to complete a rightclick or doubleclick before trapping leftclick
        Application.OnTime Now + 1 / 86400, "Sheet1.DelayedWatch"       'Note that Sheet1 is codename for worksheet (not tabname)
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub DelayedWatch()
If bTrapped = False Then
    MsgBox "Leftclick at " & cel.Address
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Brett for the comment.  I have been unfortunately ambiguous in my question - apologies.    Yes, I am using excel.  However my question relates to ActiveX controls rather than cells - I don't thin the "SelectionChange" function will work for controls.  Do you know of any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I know this reply is years late but to cancel an event, so as to prevent another event happening (on the same event) (ie. prevent single click for happening when you act on the double click) do the following;

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

        'Do your stuff in here to handle the doubleClick event

        Cancel = True 'send back a true boolean to cancel the singleClick

End Sub
```